# Проблемы с созданием адаптера для RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview

При попытке создать адаптер для `RecyclerView` возникают проблемы:

```
public class FavoriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoriteAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

В этой строчке ViewHolder вызывает ошибку: `cannot resolve symbol "ViewHolder"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем классе адаптера `FavoriteAdapter` должен быть описан класс `ViewHolder`, расширяющий абстрактный класс [`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder)

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо